# Why there are no memleaks in the following C++ while assign?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

the following code demotes my belief that I know C++ more or less. Why `valgrind` does not show any memleak here? Why I expect memleaks:

1. `B` is larger than `A`: it contains an additional member; so on assign there should be class' fields slicing.
2. ~A() does not have a virtual dtor. So when we call `delete a` only `~A()` should be called and memory allocated in B would lost.

But I receive that the calling order of dtors is: ~A(), ~B(), ~A(). Why?!

```
struct A {
  ~A()
  {
      std::cerr << "~A" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct B : A {
  int* data;

  B() : data(new int[20]) {}

  ~B()
  {
    std::cerr << "~B" << std::endl;
    delete [] data;
  }
};
```

`main()`:

```
A* a = new A;
B* b = new B;
*a = *b;

delete a;
delete b;
```

UPD:
Shame on me! I muddled deletion of an object by the pointer of base class when virtual dtor should called. Here just contents of class copying. Thanks everyone!

Comment: It's kinda hard to diagnose the delete order when you don't actually show the deletes.

Comment: I thought that the order does not matter. Thanks for the notice, I added them.

Comment: You are copying `A` part of  `B` from `*b` into `*a`. Then you are deleting `a` and `b`. `delete a;` calls `~A()`. `delete b;` calls `~B()` which calls `~A()`. There is no problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
delete a;
```

`a` is `A*`, so `A::~A` is called

```
delete b;
```

`b` is `B*` so `B::~B` is called.

Why would there be a problem?

Class fields' slicing? Yeah, so? You're just copying the `A` fields from `*b` to `*a`, nothing more than that. No memory is lost here.

Comment: I twisted the deletion by pointer to a base class with copying of contents up. It is solved. Thank's everyone!

Answer (score 1):

In `*a = *b` you are copying (and yes, slicing) `*b` to `*a`.  However, that leaves `*b` unchanged; it doesn't get sliced.  When you `delete b`, you are asking for `~B()` to be called on `*b`.

Answer (score 1):

The `*a = *b;` assignment only copy the common `A` part of the data (and `A` has no fields).

Answer (score 0):

You made a delete for each new , so there is no memleak.

```
*a =*b
```

does not allocate anything, the copy constructor just copies the part of b which can go to a, but it does not call new..

Answer (score 0):

By invoking `*a = *b;`, you're implicitly calling the assignment operator function created by the compiler that looks like this:

```
A &operator=( const A &other ){
}
```

which in your case doesn't do anything since `A` has no member variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `A` is empty, so it is entirely irrelevant for the purpose of this discussion. The only code that is involved in dynamic allocation is:

```
B* b = new B;
delete b;
```

Since you `delete` an object created with `new`, there is no leak. Furthermore, the class `B` contains sufficient code to clean up its own internal allocation in this straight-forward use-case.

(Note that `class B` is still horribly broken, since it will not survive copying or assignment. The classic Rule of Three (or Five).)

Answer (score 0):

Because what you do here is object slicing. I think you intended to have the base pointer point to the derived object and since the base destructor is not virtual, derived class destructor not called during cleanup. But that is not the case here.

```
*a = *b
```

The compiler will 'slice' those derived part of the object and copy only the base part of the object. This is not usually one want to do because this will result in an incomplete object with only base class properties and specialized derived class properties missing.